# Jenkins -Selenium Webdriver-Java: Error : DevToolsActive port does not exit

Tags: linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have automation scripts ready to execute in jenkins which is installed in linux server. But whenever I execute, it shows DevToolsActivePort does not exit. I tried searching for different solution but could not get the solution hence posting it as new question.
Can anyone help me with the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution I downgraded the version of Chromedriver 2.45 to 2.38 and it worked.